# Webcam works for a while and then video stops working until I switch USB Ports

Tags: usb, 20.04, video, webcam

I'm currently using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I bought a new webcam recently cause I was having some issues with my last one. The webcam works just fine for a while, but for some reason it stops working after a while, usually after I switch windows or close the app I'm using and only displays a black screen on cheese/guvcview/any other app. The webcam is still being recognized by the system, and the audio input never stops working.

Here's `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03f0:e111 HP, Inc DeskJet 2130 series
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1b3f:2247 Generalplus Technology Inc. GENERAL WEBCAM
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Checking `dmesg` shows this error message:

```
[   62.437596] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 2 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 1).
[  103.454839] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 2 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 1).
[  103.455161] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 2 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 1).
[  103.455333] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 2 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 1).
[  103.455491] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 2 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 1).
[  103.455644] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 2 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 1).
[  103.455823] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 2 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 1).
```

When running `guvcview` I get these error messages:

```
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
```

The only way I've been able to make the video start working again for a while is changing the USB port to which the webcam is connected.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Reboot/Shut Down system
2. Reset USB using `usbreset`
3. Reloading `uvcvideo`
4. Updating kernel (I read some people were having similar issues that were fixed on later kernel versions)

I'v seen a couple of similar issues but mos of then are either unsolved or didn't work for my particular issue. Any kind of help would be welcome!

Comment: I have exactly the same issue as you report. My camera has the same ID (so I'm guessing it uses the same sensor/controller), I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.2 fully updated with the 5.4.0-65-generic kernel. My internal webcam works flawlessly, I only have issues with this external one. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: No dice. I've switched distros a couple of times and the error persists. Only workaround I've found so far is unplugging and plugging after a few seconds. In Microsoft Teams it usually freezes and stops working mid call, on other video call software it works just fine until the call ends.

Comment: I mostly use Google Meet and Slack but the behavior you describe matched the one I've encountered. It mostly fails if I need to deactivate the camera mid-call (WFH, it happens) or switching between calls. It almost seems as if the camera remains with a lock after it has been used, preventing other apps from connecting to it.

Comment: @TiagoLeite I'm yet unable to solve this issue, but the workaround I've been using without issues for now is creating a v4l2loopback device and input the webcam video to it using `ffmpeg`, that way the webcam doesn't stop working as long as I use the virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Debian 10 when connecting my AUKEY webcam on USB3. The problem disappeared after plugging it in USB2 port.